# Docker container, custom index.html on startup

Tags: docker, containers

Been dealing with this problem for 2 days already, don't understand why it won't create the file. Cannot find any info on this online.

**Task**

Design an apache container that creates a custom `index.html` file with container's hostname in it (for load balancing testing) on startup.

Basically I need it to run `uname -n > /var/www/html/index.html` on startup. But no matter what I do file is not created.

**Tried**

Running this script in Dockerfile's CMD/ENTRYPOINT:

```
#!/bin/bash
apachectl -DFOREGROUND
/bin/uname -n | tee /var/www/html/index.html
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
apachectl -DFOREGROUND
/bin/uname -n > /var/www/html/index.html
```

Apache starts but file is not there.

But if I start container with just `ENTRYPOINT` and then attach to it and run the same script that was copied during build - it creates the file...

Tried keeping only `ENTRYPOINT ["apachectl","-DFOREGROUND"]` and running needed command with `docker run ...`, but then apache doesn't start and container exits right away.

I'm confused. Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume the issue is that you're running Apache in the foreground, so the second command in your script is never executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apachectl -DFOREGROUND` runs in the foreground.  In other words, it blocks the progress of your entrypoint script until `apachectl` exits.

I'm no Apache expert, but I suspect the easiest solution is to switch the order of the commands - do the `uname` stuff *before* starting Apache.